# How to add a conditional grand total in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, summary

I have a group running total that needs to be sum up at the report footer. Since thats not possible with CR I had to end up having another running total that refreshes "Never". But now I need to calculate some percentages at the group level based on this Grand total. Unfortunately I cannot access the value for grand total (because its another running total).
Confused?? Ok reports should look like below..

---

```
    Column 1                           | Colunm 2
    ========                            =========
```

---

| Group   200 (Running Total Refresh at Group level)  | 20% (200%1000) |
| Group   500 (Running Total Refresh at Group level)  | 50% (500%1000) |
| Group   300 (Running Total Refresh at Group level)  | 30% (300%1000) |

---

Footer  1000 (Running Total Never Refreshed)

---

But column 2 doesn't give me the correct value. it gives me 100% always means 200%200 or 500%500 etc.

Any idea how to fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx Lee, using a running total formula worked, I added following formula to the report footer,

```
numbervar Samples; 
if {product.sku}="card-sample" then 
   Samples := Samples + {@num_qty}; 

Samples;
```

Then I use this formula to calculate column 2

Answer (score 0):

I should think your report total wants to simply be a summary field not a running total. Then your column 2 value can be calculated using `running total / sum(field);`

Here is an example:

- I have two columns age and salary.
- When age > 18 i want to add the salary.

Initially I used a running total with a condition {age} > 18

That didn't work well so i deleted the running total, and created a formula: `if {age} > 18 then {salary} else 0`

I then created a summary on that formula field.

Make sense?

Comment: I cannot use summery coz I'm using a condition, means Detail column of column 1 need to be sum up using a condition. Means I sum up only one type of data from the detail section to this group running total of column 1...

Comment: what's the condition? i general steer clear of running totals. as an alternative you can create a formula field using your condition then summarize the formula field.

Comment: I tried that before,like just put the running total in to a formula and tried to summarize it, but it gives me the same answer :(

Comment: no- you can't put the running total into a formula. i have added an example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add a formula field for group percentage and then paste below code in it.

```
Group total / sum(column)
```

place this formula at your group level.

Comment: Thanks Asif, But the problem with that is I cannot use group totals in my reports coz above Group 200, 500, 300 etc are group running totals with a condition on it. If I use Group Totals I cannot use the condition.

Comment: Are 200,500,300 are three different running total or they are one running total on which you have applied condition as per group?

Comment: yes, its one running total applied at group level.. and condition is something like {product.sku}='card-sample'